# Visual Studio command prompt System.UnauthorizedAccessException while running console application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, command-line

I have a console application which accepts string agrgs[]. When I am trying to run the application by using visual studio command prompt its giving me System.UnauthorisedAccessException: Access Denied error.

Please let me know if I need to setup any access permissions for the project.

Comment: Maybe you need to run VS as an administrator to do this?

Comment: Can you put all the steps you have done? it will be easier to help you  if we have the full picture

Comment: Thank you Kjartan...I opened command prompt as Administartor. Now UnauthorisedAccessException is not raised but the control is not geeting transfer to the break points of the code.

Comment: Hi Swift..I have a console application with one class. Class contains one Main() and two other methods, one is to start 'TaskService' and one more is to stop the 'TaskService'. I have written code in such a way if the main method gets "stop" as argument it should execute stop method of Scheduler. But when running through command prompt the control is not getting transfer to the break points in main().